# How can I fix this erroring Lua BTC Miner? (

Tags: lua, bitcoin, roblox

Im trying to fix the scripts below, in order to mine btc through a roblox game server. However I have hit an error:

[image: 1]

You can find all the code here, for reference i included the script names: https://github.com/Jody7/Lua-Bitcoin-Miner

Script (Part of "Main"):

```
local PreviousBlock = require(game.ServerScriptService.BTC.GetLastBlock)()

local b = Block(PreviousBlock["data"]["hash"],  --local b = Block(PreviousBlock["data"]["hash"],
    Transactions,
    "201893210853", 
    MerkleRoot, 
    0)
```

It requires the script "GetLastBlock", which is the script below. Ive tried multiple API's because the original one was deleted, and none seemed to fix the error. Im not sure if its caused by the API or not.

```
--[[
    Returns the last block mined.
--]]

local hs = game:GetService("HttpService")
local url = "https://api-r.bitcoinchain.com/v1/blocks/10" 

return function()
    local data = hs:GetAsync(url, true)
    return hs:JSONDecode(data)
end
```

Anyone know how to fix this??
If you need any more info let me know. Thanks!

```
List of tested API's:
https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main          
https://blockchain.info/latestblock?format=json
http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/block/info/last   (This was the original APi, but the site is down now.
```

Comment: Try `PreviousBlock[0]["hash"]`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks for the response, I tried this and got the same error again, It only seems to go away for the time being when i delete "hash", but im not sure why, and it leads to a different script ending without completing.

Comment: Try `PreviousBlock[1]["hash"]`

Comment: message appears because PreviousBlock["data"] is nil, i think i had some problens with json, try to return full request response as a string and then we'll see what you got, try checking returnament with if statement or just print it, after you done response to me, so i will answer somewhere in future